# how to copy from hive table to hive table across clusters?

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

I have two hive tables with the same columns and data types, etc. and I would like to copy the data from one table to another table in a different cluster.

does hive or sqoop provide a simple way to do this?

Scenario:

```
Table A in Cluster1
Table B in Cluster2
Append table A into Table B on Cluster 2
```

Answer (score 1):

One convenient way to achieve this would be to use Hive's **[Import/Export](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ImportExport)** feature. The **Export** command exports the data of a table or partition, along with the metadata, into a specified output location. This output location can then be moved over to a different Hadoop or Hive instance and imported from there with the **Import** command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the falcon as well for doing the data replication.
Also you can use the hive context and write the code in Java or Scala to copy the data.

Comment: In hive-site xml make the changes like: 

<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
        <value>thrift://hklpadhod08:9083,thrift://hklpadhod09:9083</value>
    </property>
</configuration>

Answer (score 0):

You can use Distcp command to copy the data between clusters.But you have to first convert the table data to a file and copy the file to different cluster using the command.Usage below:

```
$ hadoop distcp (src) (dest)
```

After the file is copied in cluster 2,then you can load the file in the table.
You can find more info in this links:http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/distcp.html